# Making Off-Diagonals of Jordan Normal Form Arbitrarily Small

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, jordan-normal-form

I know that the off-diagonals of the Jordan blocks for a matrix can be made arbitrarily small, i.e. we can find a similarity transformation such that the Jordan blocks look like this (as an example):

$$ J = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & \delta & 0 \\ 0& \lambda & \delta \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix} $$

where $\delta > 0$ is arbitrarily small. In fact it is quite easy to show by using the construction of the generalized eigenvectors as follows:

$$\begin{align}
(A - \lambda I) x_1 &= 0 \\
(A - \lambda I) x_2 &= \delta x_1 \\
(A - \lambda I) x_3 &= \delta x_2
\end{align}$$

which yields

$$ A \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & \delta & 0 \\ 0& \lambda & \delta \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda \end{bmatrix} $$

However, I couldn't find any reference that mentions this "well-known" fact. Can you show a reference that mentions this?